# Using Quarkus Health check with Smallrye fault tolerance?

Tags: quarkus, rate-limiting, health-check, smallrye

When using [Smallrye health check](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-health#running-the-health-check), an endpoint like `/q/health` will be automatically added to the base URI. I would like to prevent someone ddossing this endpoint, so he cannot tear down databases or other services linked to this health check.

For customer endpoints, you can use the [smallrye-fault-tolerance](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-fault-tolerance) with `@RateLimit` annotation. But can this be used for automatic endpoints like /q/health as well? If not, what is the solution to prevent ddos like requests on the health endpoint?

Comment: That is not possible, at least not in a straightforward way. It would be possible to use the SmallRye Fault Tolerance programmatic API to implement a rate limit in a Vert.x Web handler (see e.g. https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#intercepting-http-requests), but perhaps the best for you would be to enable the dedicated management interface (https://quarkus.io/guides/management-interface-reference). Then, you will have the health endpoint on a completely different port, which doesn't have to be exposed to public internet.

Comment: @Ladicek Ok, thanks for your explanation.